# Find Value From JSON

Tags: python, json

First off, I'm sorry for the title, I didn't know how to be specific about my issue there.

Ok, I'm doing something with the League of Legends API. The data is displayed as Json and it can be found [here](http://ddragon.leagueoflegends.com/cdn/6.22.1/data/en_US/champion.json), what I want to do is loop through it. I have data from another script that displays stats from each player on a match. In those stats there is an id with the champion being played. I want to use that Id and compare with each key from the json file above and if it finds a matching key - id I can get the name of the champion. My problem is that I don't know exactly how I can iterate through each one of them, because as you can see on the file there is [THIS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S5oQg.jpg) (Posted an image because I couldn't get the indent right.

How can I access the Id of each one? Because, again, as you can see, each one has different names (Jax, Sona, Tristana, etc...) I just want the key and Name of each one. I tried using a For loop but couldn't even list the first one so I'm pretty lost this time. Thanks for any help :)

Code:

```
champ_r = requests.get("https://global.api.pvp.net/api/lol/static-data/lan/v1.2/champion?"
                           "api_key=").json()


for x in champ_r['data'][0]:
    pprint(x['id'])
```

If I run it like that I get a `KeyError: 0` and if I remove it I get `TypeError: string indices must be integers`

As an output I would like it to return the Ids and Names of each one of the champions. Something like:

```
Aatrox - Key
Ahri - Key...
```

... and so on.

Comment: Show your code. Explain what is the expected output using a more practical example.

Comment: @idjaw sorry, didn't think that the code was a must in this question. I updated it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on the sample output you are trying to get, the "key" of your dictionary is actually the name you are looking for, and the value associated with that key is a dictionary. You are looking for the "key" *key* in that dictionary. So, when you are iterating over the dictionary, your *value* is actually a dictionary. You can make your iteration easy on you, by using the *items* method in your iteration.

Furthermore, all your data is stored in the "data" key from your big json response. So, your code should look like this:

```
for key, value in champ_r['data'].items():
    print(key, value['key'])
```

Sample output of the first few lines:

```
Sona 37
Draven 119
FiddleSticks 9
Volibear 106
Pantheon 80
Singed 27
Vladimir 8
Ekko 245
```

Comment: Ah, that did the trick, didn't know about that method. Thank you very much :) And I had to use another json file because the first one was showing my api key.

Answer (score 4):

The error you are getting is because there is no 0 element in `champ_r['data']`. It is a dictionary keyed by names of champions. So getting the key of a champion should be done like `champ_r['data']['Ahri']['key']`. The other thing you need to know is that looping through a dictionary gives you the key, not the value, so your loop should look like:

```
for champ_name in champ_r['data']:
    print (champ_name)
    pprint(champ_r['data'][champ_name])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this one-liner : `result = {value['key']: value['name'] for key, value in champ_r['data'].items()}`